# matplotlib savefig is not displaying bar graph

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, matplotlib

I am trying to save multiple plots into a directory. When i run the below piece of code ,both the plots are getting saved. But when i open one of the png file is **completely** **blank**.The other plot is saved correctly.

Below is the sample code being used.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
for i in range(len(plots)):
    p1 = plots[i]
    p1.savefig("/sample/plots{}.png".format(i), bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0, dpi=100)
```

Below are objects available in plots list.

```
[<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x7f48d8118710>,
<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x7f48d632eb70>]
```

Comment: Please read [mcve] and provide such reproducible example. Otherwise it's really hard to know what you are doing and even harder(=impossible) to know why that fails.

Comment: But i am trying to run the code using a spark-submit command in the terminal. 
If i remove the first 2 lines i.e( import matplotlib and matplotlib.use("Agg')) i get RuntimeError: Invalid DISPLAY variable.

I am able to get the correct results if i remove the first 2 lines i.e(import matplotlib and matplotlib.use("Agg')) in jupyter notebook.

Comment: Why would you remove the first two lines? What you need to do here is to tell people exactly what they need to do and type in where to reproduce your error.

Comment: I was trying to highlight that i am unable to reproduce the issue in the jupyter notebook and is working fine. Only facing issues when i do a spark-submit.This issue of blank bar plot (completely blank) might be specific to running on spark(spark-submit)

Comment: The only difference b/w the jupyter notebook code and spark-submit code are the first two lines. If i remove it in the spark-submit code , i get invalid display variable error and I see that it is redundant in jupyter notebook which seems to work either way.